# How to hide packages file like example.app?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am listing directories on a outlineView and I can't find how to hide package files.

```
let urls = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url,                                                                   
                  includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isDirectoryKey],                                                                   
                  options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants])
```

I can only so skip regular files like text.txt
All files with .app extension are listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `skipsPackageDescendants` option is meant to prevent deep directory traversal from traversing *into* the packages. The flag doesn't mean "ignore all packages". It actually means "don't enumerate the contents inside the package".

`contentsOfDirectory()` doesn't do a deep directory traversal, so the option is meaningless in that context. The `enumerator(at:...)` method would honor that flag by not enumerating files inside the `.app` bundle; it would still enumerate the `.app` itself.

If you're not interested in certain kinds of files, you would use

```
let urls = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(
  at: url,
  includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isDirectoryKey],                                                                   
  options: [.skipsHiddenFiles]
).filter { $0.pathExtension != "app" }
```

Comment: Great!! It was missing filter!